# NodeJS: Updating Exif data and saving image using PIEXIF

Tags: node.js, exif

I need to update orientation tag(EXIF data) for the uploaded image. I am using **"PIEXIF"** for this. I am not using express but swagger. The code I've written is:

```
//Get the uploaded buffer
var _originalBuffer = req.swagger.params.uploadedFile.value.buffer;
let Duplex = require('stream').Duplex;

//Create stream from buffer. This stream is required later to send to cloud.
let _uploadedFileStream = new Duplex();
_uploadedFileStream.push(_originalBuffer);
_uploadedFileStream.push(null);

//Create base 64 string so that "PIEXIF" can read exif data from it.
const jpegData = "data:image/jpeg;base64, " + createStringFromBuffer(_originalBuffer, 'base64');

//Read exif data.
var _exifData = piexif.load(jpegData);

//Create a copy of exif data. Will be used to create a new image with updated orientation tag.
var _exifDataCopied = {};
for (var key in _exifData) {
    _exifDataCopied[key] = _exifData[key];
}

//Update orientation tag.
if (_exifDataCopied["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.Orientation])
    _exifDataCopied["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.Orientation] = 1;

//Example taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/piexifjs
//From here onwards, there seems to be an issue.
var exifbytes = piexif.dump(_exifDataCopied);
var newData = piexif.insert(exifbytes, createStringFromBuffer(_originalBuffer, 'binary'));

var newJpeg = new Buffer(newData);

//Create a new stream and save it as image back.
let _updatedFileStream = new Duplex();
_updatedFileStream.push(newJpeg);
_updatedFileStream.push(null);

var fs = require('fs');

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("./uploads/" + "Whatever.jpg")
```

The issue is there is no error thrown by the code. The image is also getting saved in the directory but it is corrupted. I can not preview it. Since, the code does not breaks anywhere, I am confused what could be the issue? The function to convert buffer to string with different encoding(since I need it a lot) is:

```
var createStringFromBuffer = function(_buffer, _encoding) {
    return Buffer.from(_buffer).toString(_encoding);
}
```

Can someone point out where I am mistaking? I am using the example given [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/piexifjs)